# Akka monitor children restarts

Tags: scala, akka

How can I say when the children of supervisor are getting restarted? I want to be able to send some initialization messages to the children that are restarted (after they've been recreated). Is it possible?

I could override `postRestart` at each child, but I would prefer to do this in the supervisor, as he controls the initialization. Is it possible?

I've tried watching the children, but `Terminated` doesn't seem to trigger if the child restarts

Comment: One possible solution is making children send a message to their parent on startup and making parent to reply this message with initialization message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a supervision strategy in the parent, then in its decider block you can access state of that actor (the parent) just like from a receive block. You can send there a message to the child (sender will point to the failing child). Since at that point, where this supervision block decides the fate of the child the child is already suspended, this message will be only processed by the child after restart.

Comment: That's clever. A bit hacky, but this is probably the best way to do that. Thanks